# Unknown Error: Jupyter extension cannot select interpreter

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

When I open a jupyter notebook, jupyter extension cannot select interpreter. And throw an unknown error.

I have Jupyter installed on my m1 MBP. It works perfectly in Jupyter Lab.

I guess this extension is not working on apple silicon devices?

> [2021-01-07 12:52:12.666] [renderer2] [error] An unknown error occurred. Please consult the log for more details.: Error:
> at S.getSelectedInterpreterAndThrowIfNotAvailable (/Users/lymo/.vscode-insiders/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2020.12.414227025/out/client/extension.js:49:474958)
> at async S.getKernelSpecs (/Users/lymo/.vscode-insiders/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2020.12.414227025/out/client/extension.js:49:473726)
> at async T.getKernelSpecs (/Users/lymo/.vscode-insiders/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2020.12.414227025/out/client/extension.js:9:133677)
> at async w.getKernelSelections (/Users/lymo/.vscode-insiders/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2020.12.414227025/out/client/extension.js:9:122775)
> at async Promise.all (index 0)
> at async /Users/lymo/.vscode-insiders/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2020.12.414227025/out/client/extension.js:9:124780